Path no access problems
I am trying to setup a Dotnet deployment, that are using some external denepdencies that are giving me problems. I am new to all this k8's and deployments. So far I have lots of stuff deployed with out needing disk for storage. But this new external dependency is causing me problems. Error below:
08:10:47 Fatal] Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
Unhandled exception: Access to the path '/app/keys' is denied.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/app/keys' is denied.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied

Starting out the problem was the same, but full path eg: /app/keys/{guid}.json
Tried to update my deployment over several attempts to fix error and mount volume right. Configuration can be seen below:
Deployment.yml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
      # - name: init
      #   image: busybox
      #   command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /app/keys && chmod -R 700 /app/keys"]
      #   volumeMounts:
      #   - name: auth-storage
      #     mountPath: /app/keys
      - name: auth
        image: kiksen1987/aspnetcore-identityserveraspnetidentity:v0.1.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: auth-storage
          mountPath: /app/keys
        env:
          - name: NODE_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          - name: connectionstring
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: postgresssecret
                key: connectionstring
      volumes:
      - name: auth-storage
        hostPath:
          path: /var/tmp
          type: Directory

volume.yml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: auth-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi

